# How can I insert commands when entering into mathmode and when exiting from mathmode?

Tags: errors, align, amsmath, hooks

I want to insert `\special`'s when entering into mathmode and when exiting from mathmode.

I wrote the following source code with everyhook.sty:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{everyhook}
\newcommand{\boe}{\special{b}}
\newcommand{\eoe}{\special{e}}
\PushPostHook{math}{\boe\aftergroup\eoe}
\PushPostHook{display}{\boe\aftergroup\eoe}
\begin{document}
\(x\)
\[y\]
\begin{align}z\end{align}
\end{document}
```

But this does not work. I have the following error:

```
! Improper \halign inside $$'s.
<recently read> \halign 
                        
l.10 \begin{align}z\end{align}
```

Is there good solution which works with the following three types of mathmodes?:
`\( \)`(inline), `\[ \]`(display), and `\begin{align} \end{align}`(amsmath).

Comment: `\everymath`, or `\everydisplay` for display math, will insert code when you enter math mode.

Comment: Thanks. But `\everydisplay` does not work with `\begin{align}`.  I got the same error as the case of eveyhook.sty.

Comment: One solution for `\begin{align}` is declaring a new environment that wraps `align`.

Comment: It seems difficult.  If I define a new `\begin{align}` including original `\begin{align}` and use the new one, then the new `\begin{align}` calls the original `\begin{align}`.  When the original `\begin{align}` is called, `\everydisplay` will be hooked.  Then `\everydisplay` will make the same error.   (I think that I need `\everydisplay` for (non-ams) display mathmodes, e.g. `\[ \]`. )